# prepare method executing multiple times

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

Hi I am creating a Topology using apache-storm in which my Spout is collecting data from Kakfa Topic and sending it to a bolt.

I am doing some validation over the tuple and emitting stream again for other bolt.

Now the issue is that my second bolt which is using stream of the first bolt  has a overload method `prepare(Map<String, Object> map, TopologyContext topologyContext, OutputCollector outputCollector)`
which is executing after let say every 2 seconds.

Code for topology is

```
topologyBuilder.setBolt("abc",new ValidationBolt()).shuffleGrouping(configurations.SPOUT_ID);

topologyBuilder.setBolt("TEST",new TestBolt()).shuffleGrouping("abc",Utils.VALIDATED_STREAM);
```

Code for First bolt "abc" is

```
@Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        String document = String.valueOf(tuple.getValue(4));
        if (Utils.isJSONValid(document)) {
            outputCollector.emit(Utils.VALIDATED_STREAM,new Values(document));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
        outputFieldsDeclarer.declareStream(Utils.VALIDATED_STREAM,new Fields("document"));
    }
```

While I was searching I found

```
The prepare method is called when the bolt is initialised and is 
similar to the open method in spout. It is called only once for the bolt.
It gets the configuration for the bolt and also the context of the bolt. 
The collector is used to emit or output the tuples from this bolt.
```

Link to public gist for log
[Storm topology log](https://gist.github.com/pritishjoshi94/4932c003d39b91016df305a4dee1b14c)

Comment: Is the worker crashing? Storm will only call prepare once per bolt task, but if the worker crashes and restarts, it will of course be called again.

Comment: @Stig There are no exception in the logs.
But getting some logs continuously.
attaching log in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log shows you are using LocalCluster. It is a testing/demo tool, don't use it for production workloads. Instead set up a real distributed cluster.

Regarding what is happening:

When you run topologies in a LocalCluster, Storm simulates a real cluster by just running all the components (Nimbus, Supervisors and workers) as threads in a single JVM. Your log shows these lines:

> 20:14:12.451 [SLOT_1027] INFO  o.a.s.ProcessSimulator - Begin killing process 2ea97301-24c9-4c1a-bcba-61008693971a
>
> 20:14:12.451 [SLOT_1027] INFO  o.a.s.d.w.Worker - Shutting down worker smart-transactional-data-1-1566571315 72bbf510-c342-4385-9599-0821a2dee94e 1027
>
> 20:14:15.518 [SLOT_1027] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.Slot - STATE running msInState: 33328 topo:smart-transactional-data-1-1566571315 worker:2ea97301-24c9-4c1a-bcba-61008693971a -> kill-blob-update msInState: 3001 topo:smart-transactional-data-1-1566571315 worker:2ea97301-24c9-4c1a-bcba-61008693971a
>
> 20:14:15.540 [SLOT_1027] INFO  o.a.s.d.w.Worker - Launching worker for smart-transactional-data-1-1566571315

The LocalCluster is shutting down one of the simulated workers, because one of the blobs (e.g. topology jar, topology configuration, other types of shared files, see more at https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/distcache-blobstore.html) in the blobstore changed. Normally when this happens in a real cluster, the worker JVM will be killed, the blob will be updated and the worker will restart. Since you are using LocalCluster, it just kills the worker thread and restarts it. This is why you are seeing multiple invocations of `prepare`.

Comment: I tried to run it with StormSubmitter and it worked as expected.
Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Is there is any way that I can achieve the same using Local Cluster.?

Comment: If you really want to execute something only once in a LocalCluster, just run it either in your topology setup code, or initialize a static variable somewhere.

Comment: Is there is any example for that.
I am very new to storm.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. When I say your topology setup code, I mean the part where you set up the TopologyBuilder. You can just run whatever else you need to run in there.

Comment: You can of course also just put a static boolean field in your bolt, and only run prepare if that field is false. Once you run prepare, you set the field to true. That will work to prevent LocalCluster from running prepare multiple times, while still allowing distributed mode Storm to work.